# Laravel 4.2 custom error handler not working

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-4

I am trying to handle InvalidArgumentException in a custom way.  In app/start/global.php I have the following code block after the built in `App::error(Exception $exception... block`:

```
App::error(function(InvalidArgumentException $exception, $code){

//    die('last');

    $exceptionData['exception'] = $exception;
    $exceptionData['code'] = $code;

    ExceptionNotificationHandlerController::notify($exceptionData);

});
```

die()ing, breakpoints, etc all suggest to me that it never goes into that block of code when I throw an InvalidArgumentException.  Help?

Comment: Have you tried it without the $code parameter the signatures in the examples only have the $exception parameter not sure if the signature makes a difference when its trying to load.

Comment: @MarkDavidson Yes, I've tried it with without the $code parameter.  Same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, just for anyone having this problem it seems that having `'debug' => true` set in app/config/app.php prevents you from using your custom exception handlers properly.  Once I set that to false all my problems went away.  Annoyingly, you're supposed have this set to true while working in local environment.  Even more annoyingly, it appears that once you set debug to false you can no longer get the exception message with `$exception->getMessage()`.